# Construct: Rebuffered stream

Tags: python, performance, io, stream

This is part of the [Construct](https://github.com/construct/construct) library. Rebuffered is used to turn a seekless/tellless stream like from a socket or pipe into a seekable/tellable one like a BytesIO or a file.

If `tailcutoff` is provided, only that amount of bytes is kept counting from the end of last read write operation backwards. Otherwise entire stream is cached.

```
class RebufferedBytesIO:
    __slots__ = ["substream","offset","rwbuffer","moved","tailcutoff"]

    def __init__(self, substream, tailcutoff=None):
        self.substream = substream
        self.offset = 0
        self.rwbuffer = b""
        self.moved = 0
        self.tailcutoff = tailcutoff

    def read(self, count):
        startsat = self.offset
        endsat = startsat + count
        if startsat < self.moved:
            raise IOError("could not read because tail was cut off")
        while self.moved + len(self.rwbuffer) < endsat:
            newdata = self.substream.read(128*1024)
            self.rwbuffer += newdata
            if not newdata:
                sleep(0)
        data = self.rwbuffer[startsat-self.moved:endsat-self.moved]
        self.offset += count
        if self.tailcutoff is not None and self.moved < self.offset - self.tailcutoff:
            removed = self.offset - self.tailcutoff - self.moved
            self.moved += removed
            self.rwbuffer = self.rwbuffer[removed:]
        if len(data) < count:
            raise IOError("could not read enough bytes, something went wrong")
        return data

    def write(self, data):
        startsat = self.offset
        endsat = startsat + len(data)
        while self.moved + len(self.rwbuffer) < startsat:
            newdata = self.substream.read(128*1024)
            self.rwbuffer += newdata
            if not newdata:
                sleep(0)
        self.rwbuffer = self.rwbuffer[:startsat-self.moved] + data + self.rwbuffer[endsat-self.moved:]
        self.offset = endsat
        if self.tailcutoff is not None and self.moved < self.offset - self.tailcutoff:
            removed = self.offset - self.tailcutoff - self.moved
            self.moved += removed
            self.rwbuffer = self.rwbuffer[removed:]
        return len(data)

    def seek(self, at, whence=0):
        if whence == 0:
            self.offset = at
            return self.offset
        elif whence == 1:
            self.offset += at
            return self.offset
        else:
            raise ValueError("seeks only with whence 0 and 1")

    def seekable(self):
        return True

    def tell(self):
        return self.offset

    def tellable(self):
        return True

    def cachedfrom(self):
        return self.moved

    def cachedto(self):
        return self.moved + len(self.rwbuffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no docstring for the class. What kind of thing does an object belonging to this class represent? The text from your post would make a good start.
2. There's no docstring for the `__init__` method. What do I pass for `substream`? What does `tailcutoff` mean? Again, the text from your post would make a good start.
3. There are no docstrings for the `cachedfrom` and `cachedto` methods. What do these return?
4. The `cachedfrom` and `cachedto` methods do not take any arguments. Would it make sense for these to be properties instead of methods?
5. Attributes like `substream` and `rwbuffer` do not appear to be intended to be used outside of the class implementation. It is conventional to give these names starting with `_`. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables):

   > Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables.
6. The idea seems to be to create an object that acts like Python's built-in buffered I/O objects. But it doesn't implement the whole interface — for example, there's no [`close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) method, no [`closed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.closed) property, and so on.

   It would make sense to inherit from the abstract base class [`io.BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) so that you get implementations of all the methods (even if some of them are only stubs).
7. The number `128*1024` appears in two places without explanation. It should have a name, something like `_chunk_size`, and it might make sense for it to be a keyword argument to the constructor.
8. In the `seek` method I would use the constants `io.SEEK_SET` and `io.SEEK_CUR` instead of the numbers 0 and 1. That's because the named constants make the intention clear.
9. [`BufferedIOBase.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read) has this behaviour:

   > If the argument is omitted, `None`, or negative, data is read and returned until EOF is reached.

   This behaviour is not implemented by `RebufferedBytesIO.read`. This kind of incompatibility might prevent someone from being able to pass a `RebufferedBytesIO` object to a function that was expecting an [`io.BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) object.
10. `RebufferedBytesIO.read` raises an exception on a short read:

    ```
    if len(data) < count:
        raise IOError("could not read enough bytes, something went wrong")
    ```

    But for `BufferedIOBase` streams, [short reads are possible](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read).
11. The code for reading more chunks from the substream until the target position is reached is duplicated between the `read` and `write` methods. This should be refactored into its own method.
12. The code for doing the tail cut-off is duplicated between the `read` and `write` methods. This should be refactored into its own method.
13. Cutting off the tail using:

    ```
     self.rwbuffer = self.rwbuffer[removed:]
    ```

    is inefficient. In the worst case this code ends up copying the whole of `rwbuffer` on each read or write, which would be disastrous for performance.
14. The logic for reading a single chunk from the underlying stream looks like this:

    ```
    newdata = self.substream.read(128*1024)
    self.rwbuffer += newdata
    ```

    but the documentation for [`RawIOBase.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) says:

    > If the object is in non-blocking mode and no bytes are available, `None` is returned.

    If this happens, the `+=` will fail with `TypeError: can't concat bytes to NoneType`.
15. The logic for reading chunks from the underlying stream looks like this:

    ```
    while self.moved + len(self.rwbuffer) < endsat:
        newdata = self.substream.read(128*1024)
        self.rwbuffer += newdata
        if not newdata:
            sleep(0)
    ```

    If the underlying stream is blocking, the `sleep(0)` is not necessary (because the `read` blocks if there is nothing to return. But if the underlying stream is non-blocking, then:

    > A `BlockingIOError` is raised if the underlying raw stream is in non blocking-mode, and has no data available at the moment.

    So in neither the blocking case nor the non-blocking case is there any obvious reason to have a `sleep` here.

Comment: (1 2 3 5 6) Its used only internally so those dont matter. (7) Arbitrary buffer size, dont matter. (9) Applied. (10) Short reads are errors within the library. (11 12) Not exact duplicate, wont worth the effor or separatin code. (13) Worthy point, could you provide implementation?  (14 15) Applied, but arent those mutually exclusive?

Comment: (1–5) documentation is not just for end users, but for the benefit of anyone who has to maintain code (including yourself in a few years time, when you've forgotten the details). It's not easy to maintain code if you don't know what it is supposed to do. (13) I'm available for hire and my rates are reasonable. (15) In this point, I'm imagining that you've fixed the bug in point (14).